# How to turn on computer before monitor in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a htpc.  I have an ir blaster to turn on my projector (monitor).  I wish to turn on my computer which would then run a script to turn on my projector via the ir blaster.  If the computer boots before the projector is turned on the computer does not detect the projector even after it is turned on and all I get is a blue screen.  Is there anyway around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [lirc](http://www.lirc.org/) and an ir blaster, but from what this sounds like it won't solve your problem.
It seems like your display manager doesn't come up if it can't find a monitor, because your projector is off.
So even if it boots, and runs your script turning the projector on, that's still after the display manager already failed.

What i could think of is a simple script through cron, running every minute, that just checks if the display manager failed, and tries to restart it. 
That should bring your projector back up, if it was turned on at any time after the machine has been booted, at maximum taking a minute.

To do that, make a script like

```
#!/bin/bash 

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
export SHELL="/bin/bash"

if [ $(systemctl status lightdm | grep Active: | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}') == "failed" ]; then
    service lightdm restart
fi
```

save it, as say `lightdm-restart.sh`, and make it executable

```
chmod +x lightdm-restart.sh
```

Then open roots crontab with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the following to the bottom

```
# try to restart lightdm every minute if it failed  
* * * * * /path/to/lightdm-restart.sh
```

Comment: Thank you.  Why don't I just write a script that turns on the projector wiht the ir blaster waits 10 seconds and then uses what you showed to restart the display manager.

Comment: That would work too, i don't have your ir blaster or specific setup so i can't help out much for configuring it. Check the lirc documentation here http://www.lirc.org/html/ on how to do that. But it basically would boil down to something like this (when lirc is configured to your setup), "irsend SEND_ONCE <yourdevice> KEY_POWER; sleep 10; /path/to/lightdm-restart.sh". To autorun this on boot with cron just change the "* * * * *" to "@reboot"

Comment: I have an irdroid